# Selecting records where a TimeDate = now() =< 2 years from now

Tags: php, mysql, date

Im a bit new to php and sql and I have this problem:

I have a DateTime field called EndDate.

I need to select and only show records that are current.

Ive tried many variations of the following:

```
SELECT EndDate FROM booking ORDER BY EndDate ASC WHERE EndDate > NOW()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fulfill your requirement given in the title of your question, use DATE_ADD:

```
SELECT EndDate FROM booking 
WHERE EndDate >= NOW() AND EndDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) 
ORDER BY EndDate ASC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot im gonna copy this and never forget it hehe - helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

corrrect Syntax is `select .. from .. where .. order by`:

```
SELECT EndDate FROM booking WHERE EndDate > NOW() ORDER BY EndDate ASC
```